# Processing meshes + MatLab

Tags: matlab, 3d, processing

I'm trying to generate 3D meshes in Processing to be read later in MatLab.

I've managed to install Hemesh (a 3D mesh library for Processing) and I can work my way around the creation of meshes. However, so much work so that I can read them later in MatLab. I need the meshes to be saved as `.mesh` file (or similar). Basically, it can be a `.txt` file as well, but I need to have something like:

**Vertices**

`VX` `VY` `VZ` coordinates

(list of coordinates of the meshe's vertices)

**Tetrahedra**

`Vertex1` `Vertex2` `Vertex3` `Vertex4`

(list of vertices used to compute the tetrahedra, it can be the index of the corresponding `VX`, `VY` ,`VZ` coordinates of the respective vertices use to construct each tetrahedra)

Is it possible to take this values out of the Processing routines? Have you ever done something similar? Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can just write your meshes into a file like this:

```
class Vertex{int x,y,z;}
Vertex meshes[] = new Vertex[100];

//populate the meshes array

PrintWriter out = createWriter("output.meshes");

for(int i=0; i<meshes.length; i++){
    out.println(meshes[i].x + " " +
                meshes[i].y + " " +
                meshes[i].z);
}
```

Proceed the same way for the tetrahedra.